# Custom search directive

Tags: angularjs

I am building a small search app using AngularJS and Elasticsearch. I'm using AngularJS UI Bootstrap Typeahead for autocomplete functionality. Now I'm trying to create a custom search directive for the search functionality. Still learning AngularJS directives...

I should just be able to add the UI Bootstrap Typeahead directive to this custom search directive, right? (as an attr).

So I would just need to pass the suggestion function, search function and search terms (ng-model) to my custom search directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using examples and *citing* from [Angular Developer Guide: Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Q1: "I should just be able to add the UI Bootstrap Typeahead directive to this custom search directive, right? (as an attr)."

A1: As your custom directives are dependency injected, you should be able to use any Angular component that you would normally dependency inject:

*"Just like the module.controller API, the function argument in module.directive is dependency injected. Because of this, we can use $interval and dateFilter inside our directive's link function."*

```
angular.module('docsTimeDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
}])
.directive('myCurrentTime', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', function($interval, dateFilter) {
```

Q2: "So I would just need to pass the suggestion function, search function and search terms (ng-model) to my custom search directive?"

A2: That is one way to do it, however your directive would be dependent on the controller host to have the functionality. [If you go with this route you would do so with the & operator.](http://plnkr.co/edit/sp00bjwrV6hNoVL7NeKY?p=info)

I would however go with the [link property](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjU2fX17kfSe2paOxSJd?p=preview). Here your directive can have the code needed for calculations, and you can inject the search parameters into it with the = operator.

**Link example of mine.** I think you should be able to convert it to your problem easily :)

Directive:

```
function statisticsTableDirective(common) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                tabledata: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'app/statistics/statisticsTable.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var vm = scope;
                vm.isLastMonth = isLastMonth;

                function isLastMonth(index) {
                    return index+1 === new Date().getMonth();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

In the statisticsTable.html I can now use isLastMonth as it were directly on the scope. Like in a simple ng-class:

```
ng-class="::{highlight : isLastMonth($index)}"></td>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, can you please elaborate a little bit on how you would do it using the link property?

Comment: I've been watching some videos on the link property for directives and it seems like a better way to pass functions and variables to a directive. The "attribute" way seems like the "basic" way and the link property gives more flexibility, would you agree?

Comment: OK I added a link example of mine. Hope you can use it. Basically you can define functions inside the directive on that scope, and pass parameters.

Comment: thanks very much! So it seems like I could define my suggestion function and search function in the link property if I wanted to? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes you could do that!